# Cordova - How to make an online app/game with a Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, server

I've been studying node.js for a while and now want to transition to connecting to my node.js server with my cordova app.

Wherever I look, I can't seem to find any real answers or tutorials.

If I go to myIP:8080 with my phone, it connects to the server, but how would I do it with a cordova app? Everything I try that's even remotely close I end up with a bunch of errors. Guide me please. I'm confused :/

P.S I initially tried making a game using a send/receive `XMLHttpRequest()` with PHP/MySQL, code worked but extremely laggy.. had to find out the hard way that it is not the way to go

Comment: Do you want to use nodejs server to host your API or you want some socket connection?

Comment: Hi Zohaib. Basically, I want to make a multiplayer game, all files are on the app already, only information (e.g x y coordinates; action button) passes between the players. I do not want to "just connect to browser to play" sort (If that's what you're asking)
Perfect example would be something like Agar.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `Socket.io` with Nodejs to get real time data from all clients.

You app will connect to your server app which will be hosted somewhere. If you are running server code on localhost (on your computer or desktop) you need to expose this using some service like `ngrok`. Your app will send player coordinates to server which will broadcast those coordinates to all clients/players and same for all players. If still you need any help, let me know.

In you client app, in html page load this script, not exactly but similar, it will create a socket connection (duplex connection) between your app and server app. Then you will send your coordinates to server app using `socket.emit()`.

```
<script>
  var socket = io('server ip');

  $('#button').click(function(){
    socket.emit('coordinates', {x: 1, y: 2});
  });

  // server can send you different events/data

  // 'moved' can be any event, its name can be 'abc'
  socket.on('moved', function(data){
    // process this data
  });
</script>
```

Here are some resources.

- http://socket.io/
- https://github.com/techpines/express.io

Comment: I've been reading and following every tutorial I could get my hands on. But they don't seem to have any "client", only server. You just go to localhost:8080 and that's it. They show `server.listen(8080);` on server side, ok... but how do I make a connection to the server? Do I use `window.open('myIP:8080');` and `XMLHttpRequest()` it? Idk I'm pretty wired, tired and confused, been trying to make it work for days

Comment: For example, the socket.io website's tutorial you have provided is: `And if you point your browser to http://localhost:3000:` after starting the server.. I don't want to go on the actual browser, I just want to send/receive information from it

Comment: @rery You don't need to open localhost, your cordova app is just an html app, so you will load above script in your app page which will connect your app to server. whenever your plaer will make a move, you will send your player's coordinates to server using `socket.emit()` syntax. and when server will receive your coordinates, it will send your coordinates to all connected clients like you are listening for `data` event. if server emits/broadcasts an event `data` with some player's coordinates and his name, you will get those in your registered callback with `daat` event

Comment: Thanks to you I found this nice tutorial: http://socket.io/socket-io-with-apache-cordova/ 

I'm very relieved but when I run the app on my phone android studio logcat gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: socket is not defined`

Comment: I assume I need to add some sort of connection to the server which tutorial seems to not included? Or am I messing up?

Comment: In tutorial, `app.initialize()` method is not given, that is what I placed in my answer. that is the socket object.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help Zohaib. i think app.initialize is for cordova.js, it isn't a problem. I understand how to emit/on sockets, but the confusing I have is the `var socket = io('http://192.168.0.14:3000');` (which was my problem/question from the very start) I added it it on top of the code and it took error away but I have not received any alerts. I put a random "Hello" alert after the code to check and only the Hello alert shows - so I assume it didn't connect to server

Comment: I think, your IP is not global. YOu can test this by adding a route `/` with `Hello World` response and open url in browser to see if it opens or not. I think it will not open .. You need to do something to make it global.

Comment: For some reason, I didn't get the alert message. But I vaguely noticed my server(console) stating `socket connected` every time I opened app! I can't thank you enough, my problem has been resolved :) I can now work on this with relaxation :D